# jquery add class on all input selected

Tags: jquery

I have a html form where I want highlight fields that have been selected via jquery.
to do this I have done in this way

```
<select id="s1">
 <option value="">--</option>
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2" selected>2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select id="s2">
 <option value="">--</option>
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

<select id="s3">
 <option value="">--</option>
 <option value="1" selected>1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
</select>

etc..
```

js

```
if ($("select#s1 option:selected").prop("value") != '') {
 $("select#s1").addClass("blu-border");
}

if ($("select#s2 option:selected").prop("value") != '') {
 $("select#s2").addClass("blu-border");
}

if ($("select#s3 option:selected").prop("value") != '') {
 $("select#s3").addClass("blu-border");
}

etc..
```

I would like to know if it is possible to do this using only one command for all selected input fields. 
Like this that I use to reset all the form fields.

```
$(":input").prop('selectedIndex', 0);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check whether the selected options value is not blank, so

```
$('select').removeClass('add').filter(function () {
    console.log(this, this.value)
    return this.value != ''
}).addClass('add')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ap8sH/)

Or

```
$('select').removeClass('add').has('option:selected[value!=""]').addClass('add')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ap8sH/2/)

Note: The removeClass() is used to remove the previously added class, in my test case.